# Reading File from a Remote machine

Tags: express

What is the best way to read local file from remote virtual machine? Actually I want to share file between two servers which are hosting my website on openstack cloud?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Instead of asking for "the best way", which is very fuzzy and unclear, try asking "How can I ..?" or "Is there a faster way to ..?". Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a remote file from a remote virtual machine, you can use FTP, implement a FTP server on your remote machine and connect to it to read the file.